# Eclipse plug-in (OpenEdge Architect 10.2B) blocked by firewall

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, firewall, progress-4gl, openedge

Yesterday I installed OpenEdge Architect 10.2B (that is Object Oriented Progress adopted to Eclipse IDE) on my Windows 7 premium platform. The installation went fine without any error messages.

When I start OpenEdge Architect I get the following error message:

```
"Not licensed to run OpenEdge Architect for version 10.2B".
```

This error message is strange since it is not the case.

Also, it seems like parts of the Eclipse-plugin are blocked

1. The main menu looks ok
2. In the views there are error messages like: "Could not create the view: Plug-in com.openedge.pdt.text was unable to load class com.openedge.pdt.text.explorer.OEExplorer...."

I noted that if I open my firewall (F-Secure) and choose to allow all, then everything works fine but then, of course, the computer is vulnerable. Then I thought I should abandon the F-secure firewall and use Windows firewall instead, setting up exceptions for OE Architect. But at this point I can not see what the exceptions should be since there are plenty of processes involved!

Any suggestion on how to proceed? How can I see what is blocked (is it Eclipse related or Eclipse plug-in related or is it something else in the OpenEdge package?)

---

*Migrated from https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/*

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue, this is how I did it:

- Open F-secure, change the firewall setting to allow all.
- Open Windows firewall, turn it on.
- Start OpenEdge Architect
- A warning from Windows firewall appears a .\jre\bin/javaw.exe is blocked by the firewall, check the allow boxes and press "Allow access".

Done.

Answer (score 1):

It my be that the license manager is a process itself thatthe Architect is only connecting to - thus the problem with the firewalls. Most of this stuff is either a java process or one of the processes from your \bin directory. To figure out which process is trying to open which port, open a command shell (windows+r, enter 'cmd' and press 'run'), and then run 'netstat -ao', which gives you a list of all processes running and the ports thy are listening on. If you search this list while running the Architect with your firewall turned off, you might be able to find the processes involved with licensing (either a java process or one of the binaries from the aforementioned 'bin' folder).

hope that helps!

Comment: +1 I think you are on the right track! It seems like it is a Java issue.

Comment: Added my solution, which is a little easier ans strait forward. Thanks again!